# PhoneGap + JqueryMobile click not function for android emulator

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-emulator

I am using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

I can click div when I test with my browser but if I tried it in my android emulator 4.0, it does not show any response. I read online sources said that jquery mobile click should use $(document).live('click',function()..) and my code is

```
<div data-role="content">             
        <p><img level='1' src="css/images/level1.png"/><a id="level" level="1" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Home</a></p>
        <p><img level='2' src="css/images/level2.png"/><a id="level" level="2" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">School</a></p>
        <p><img level='3' src="css/images/level3.png"/><a id="level" level="3" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Restaurant</a></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('a#level').live('click', function () {
    alert("XX"+ $(this).attr("level"));
    sessionStorage.StudyLevel = $(this).attr("level"); 
});
</script>
```

alert showed in my browser but nothing happen in my emulator. Same goes with other swipe and tap event not execute in my emulator. Have I missed something?

Comment: did you find any solution of your issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with class rather than id:-

```
<div data-role="content">             
    <p><img level='1' src="css/images/level1.png"/><a id="level1" class='selCls' level="1" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Home</a></p>
    <p><img level='2' src="css/images/level2.png"/><a id="level2" class='selCls'  level="2" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">School</a></p>
    <p><img level='3' src="css/images/level3.png"/><a id="level3" class='selCls'  level="3" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Restaurant</a></p>
```

And also

```
 $('body').on('click', '.selCls', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      alert('clicked');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change sequence in jquery files in header like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $('a#level').bind('click', function(event, ui) {
     //code here.
   });
});
</script>
```

And let me know is this worked or not.

Comment: I changed the sequence (javascript moved to header) but it still does not trigger the alert I put inside the function click.

Answer (score -1):

According to phonegap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) you should listen to this event before everything else:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API
    // Put your code here
}
```

For events attachment you can use (recommended) jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You also have duplicate ids for imgs, thats not recomended. You can use a dummy class and search for that instead like:

```
<div data-role="content">             
        <p><img level='1' src="css/images/level1.png"/><a id="level1" level="1" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Home</a></p>
        <p><img level='2' src="css/images/level2.png"/><a id="level2" level="2" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">School</a></p>
        <p><img level='3' src="css/images/level3.png"/><a id="level3" level="3" class="handler" href="wordlist.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Restaurant</a></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('a.handler').on('click', function () {
    alert("XX"+ $(this).attr("level"));
    sessionStorage.StudyLevel = $(this).attr("level"); 
});
</script>
```